# iPhone static library creation

Tags: iphone, static-libraries

I have created a static library LibA.a which includes some codes and another static library LibB.a. When I use this static library LibA.a in a new project I get many errors like these:

> File1.h no such file or directory.

This file File1.h and others showing error are present in LibB.a.

**Edit 1:** I am using XCode 4.0.1

**Edit 2:** Now while creating my static library, I have made the header file public whose methods the user can use in their project. My static library references another static library named XWidget.a. I have added it into my static library's "Link Binary with Libraries" and also in the direct dependency. Then created my static library. Now I am testing my library in a demo project. In Header Search Paths of demo project I have added the path of my static library's public header file.When I run it, the header files which are present in the inner static library XWidget.a are not found. Giving errors like FileA.h: no such file or directory. Should I somehow provide the path of inner static library (XWidget.a) also? If yes then how? Or what else am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the header files in the project where you want to interface with the library.

Comment: Actually those header files which are present inside the static library (in the "project" domain of "copy headers") are not found in the main project and giving the above mentioned error. I do not want to keep them in public domain so that it cannot be seen.

Comment: some header files MUST be public so that developers can use the library

Comment: @ phix23 : Please have a look at Edit 2. I have tried what you said but some more errors are coming.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the big project button in Xcode's file management tab on the sidebar, select your target, click Build Phases, and pull down the drop down menu titled "Compile Sources".  Then make sure all the necessary .m, **not .h**, files are there.

I've run into this problem a couple times myself, I hope this helps you!